# Is there a way to check if two classes are identical in python?

Tags: python

*edit*:
Given N classes with fixed attributes, my goal is to find the minimal set of unique classes that will be a superset of all N classes.

I want to check if two classes (not **instances** of these classes) are identical in the sense that they have identical class attributes.

The trivial approach is to override `__eq__` and `__hash__`[1](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__hash__#object.__hash__), but this will only allow comparing instances of the classes.

I wonder if this is even possible as it seems like python uses `id` to check for equality between the classes which can not be overridden.

The desired outcome is something like this:

```
    class FOO:
        SOME_ATTR=3
    class BAR1:
        SOME_ATTR=3
    class BAR2:
        SOME_ATTR=1
```

```
set(FOO, BAR1, BAR2) == set(FOO, BAR2)
```

Comment: What does it mean for a *class* to be identical? I would not consider `BAR1` and `BAR2` to be identical in your case. `FOO` and `BAR1` maybe. But code that uses classes *may* do things like `if instanceof(o, FOO)`, in which case they would not be identical at all…

Comment: You might want metaclasses.

Comment: Also, in addition to what deceze said, classes can be mutated in Python. They don't have to stay the same. It's true that in good code they *should* stay the same, but there's no code that's perfect and completely standards-following.

Comment: There is no tool for comparing classes, because having 2 identical classes is a sign of bad design in the first place.

Comment: Perhaps I should have explained the use-case (as I agree that having 2 identical classes might indicate bad design). These classes are auto-generated (using Jinja2 templates) from external properties I can not know in advance. The aim is to minimize the generated code by finding "duplicate" classes.

Comment: FWIW, *classes generated from Jinja templates?!* That sounds like a terrible idea. *If* you need to define classes at runtime, you can do so using `type()`, not a templating system.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know if the attributes of classes are the same, you can use the `inspect.getmembers()` function and filter for attributes without dunders. Note that attributes of classes are mutable!

```py
import inspect

class FOO:
    SOME_ATTR=3

    def my_func():
        pass

class BAR1:
    SOME_ATTR=3

class BAR2:
    SOME_ATTR=1



def compare_classes(class1: type, class2: type) -> bool:
    attr_class1 = inspect.getmembers(class1, lambda a:not(inspect.isroutine(a)))
    attr_class2 = inspect.getmembers(class2, lambda a:not(inspect.isroutine(a)))
    set_class1 = set([a for a in attr_class1 if not(a[0].startswith('__') and a[0].endswith('__'))])
    set_class2 = set([a for a in attr_class2 if not(a[0].startswith('__') and a[0].endswith('__'))])
    return set_class1 == set_class2


print(compare_classes(FOO, BAR1))
print(compare_classes(BAR1, BAR2))
```

Outcome:

```
True
False
```

Comment: Looks great. My goal is to find the minimal set that will include all "unique" classes within N given classes. pairwise comparison will require an order of O(N^2) comparisons. If I was able to implement a "hash" function for a class, this can be done in O(N).

Comment: @JarroVGIT: run your code on the testcase in my answer  in case it was not your intention to consider a sub-class of a class to be a class attribute .

Answer (score 0):

To get a set of attributes of a Python class, for example

```
class MyClass:
   my_attr: 2
```

you can use

```
set(x for x in MyClass.__dict__.keys() if not x.startswith('__'))
```

then compare the sets of the classes

Comment: Note that this doesn't take into account parent attributes.

Answer (score -2):

Try:

```
class minSetCls():
    def __init__(self, list_of_classes):
        self._dctCAttrsCName = {}
        self.add(list_of_classes)

    def add(self, list_of_classes):
        for c in list_of_classes:
            attrdict = {}
            clasdict = c.__dict__
            for key, val in clasdict.items():
                if not key.startswith('_') and not callable(val): 
                    attrdict[key] = val
            self._dctCAttrsCName[ tuple(sorted(list(attrdict.items()))) ] = c.__name__

    def get(self): 
        return sorted(self._dctCAttrsCName.values())

mSCs = minSetCls([BAR1, BAR2, BAR3]) 
print( mSCs.get() )
mSCs.add([BAR4, BAR5]) 
print( mSCs.get() )
```

on:

```
class BAR1: # << same as BAR3   ----
    SOME_ATTR=3
    class BAR1sub1:
        SOME_ATTR = 3
class BAR2: # >> UNIQUE         BAR2
    SOME_ATTR=2
class BAR3: # >> MASKS BAR1     BAR3
    SOME_ATTR=3
class BAR4: # << same as BAR5   ----
    SOME_OTHER_ATTR=4
    class BAR4sub1:
        SOME_ATTR = 4
class BAR5: # >> MASKS BAR4     BAR5
    SOME_OTHER_ATTR=4
```

what will give:

```
['BAR2', 'BAR3']
['BAR2', 'BAR3', 'BAR5']
```